# using <select> to sort mysql database but nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Here is my MySQL code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY ID ASC;";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<p><table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Film Name</th>
    <th>Producer</th>
    <th>Year Published</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Function</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$row["ID"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["FilmName"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Producer"]."</td>
        <td>".$row['YearPublished']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Stock']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Price']."</td>
        <td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Edit</a>
        <td><a href=\"delete.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Delete</a>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
 $sort = @$_POST['order'];
if ($_GET['sortby'] == '1')
{
     "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";
}
elseif ($_GET['sortby'] == '2')
{
    "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName DESC";
}
```

Form code is here:

```
<form name="sort" action="" method="post">
    <select name="sortby">
    <option value="1">Film Name - Ascending</option>
    <option value="2">Film Name - Descending</option>
    <input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
</select> 
<form>
```

I'm trying to sort my table by filmname either ascending or descending. However, when I click submit for either button, the database does not does not do anything and nothing happens. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: i think ID is integer and it is auto-incremented thats why you do not see any sorting

Comment: you should assign you $sql in you if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just rearrange the lines to something like below

```
$sort = @$_POST['order'];

if (isset($_POST['sortby']) && $_POST['sortby'] == '1')
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['sortby']) && $_POST['sortby'] == '2')
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName DESC";
}
else 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY ID ASC;";
}
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<p><table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Film Name</th>
    <th>Producer</th>
    <th>Year Published</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Function</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$row["ID"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["FilmName"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Producer"]."</td>
        <td>".$row['YearPublished']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Stock']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Price']."</td>
        <td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Edit</a>
        <td><a href=\"delete.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Delete</a>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the output

Comment: method = post not a get so i can't use $_GET['sortby']

Comment: I have editied the answer. Please have a look now. You were using the post method therefore, `sortby` will also come in `$_POST`. I was taking it from `$_GET` from your question.

Comment: Boom! Worked like a treat! Thanks

Comment: What issue? which code? How can you say I have posted your code? `else` is required in case no form is submitted, there should be a default query to run.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary check your code there no need to else,default come in asc order

Comment: @ParthChavda How will it come by default when we have not given the query anywhere. We need to specify the default behaviour at least once.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion of @AshishChoudhury, you need to **use `$_POST['sortby']`** instead of using `$_GET['sortby']` as your form use POST not GET.

USE this one

```
if (isset($_POST['sortby']) && $_POST['sortby'] == '1')
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['sortby']) && $_POST['sortby'] == '2')
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName DESC";
}
else 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY ID ASC;";
}
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<p><table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Film Name</th>
    <th>Producer</th>
    <th>Year Published</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Function</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$row["ID"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["FilmName"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Producer"]."</td>
        <td>".$row['YearPublished']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Stock']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Price']."</td>
        <td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Edit</a>
        <td><a href=\"delete.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Delete</a>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but no change unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY ID ASC;";
```

you want to reorder

So before it you should choose GET or POST but for example i will use post

```
$order = $_POST['order'];// this can be DESC or ASC
```

and then $order put into query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName $order;";
```

so after posting order in your query result is changed

Answer (score 0):

$sort = $_POST['order'];

$sortBy = (isset($_GET['sortby'])&& $_GET['sortby']!=0 )?$_GET['sortby']:0;

switch ($sortBy) {

```
case "1":

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";

    break;

case "2":

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName DESC";

    break;

default:

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";
```

}

$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

```
echo "<p><table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Film Name</th>
<th>Producer</th>
<th>Year Published</th>
<th>Stock</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Function</th>
</tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

echo "
    
        ".$row["ID"]."

```
    <td>".$row["FilmName"]."</td>

    <td>".$row["Producer"]."</td>

    <td>".$row['YearPublished']."</td>

    <td>".$row['Stock']."</td>

    <td>".$row['Price']."</td>

    <td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Edit</a>

    <td><a href=\"delete.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Delete</a>

</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

}

else
 {

```
echo "0 results";
```

}

Comment: Improve formatting of your code snippet. Also add text/comments to explain it.

Answer (score -1):

See now i am updated my code  check it. now its work.

```
$sort = @$_POST['order'];

    if (isset($_POST['sortby']) && $_POST['sortby'] == '2')
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName DESC";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductManagement ORDER BY FilmName ASC";
    }



      $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<p><table>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Film Name</th>
        <th>Producer</th>
        <th>Year Published</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Function</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$row["ID"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["FilmName"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["Producer"]."</td>
            <td>".$row['YearPublished']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Stock']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Price']."</td>
            <td><a href=\"edit.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Edit</a>
            <td><a href=\"delete.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."\">Delete</a>
        </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

> $_POST use because in your form method = "post"

Comment: This will give undefined variable `$sql` error, for the first time when the form is not posted.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary thanks for your comment i have updated my ans